# Software that can check for broken links on an intranet

Tags: windows, hyperlink, intranet

I’m looking for software to run on a Windows machine that can test the integrity of my organization’s intranet site.

Something akin to the [W3C Link Checker](https://validator.w3.org/checklink).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For exactly that purpose I am using [Xenu's Link Sleuth](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html). It's free, small and fast with simple and easy to use interface.

Comment: +1 but It can't handle inline images (such as `data:image/svg+xml;base64;...`) correctly.